# Bootstrap wysiwyg not able to add hyperlinks in IE 10 & IE 11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rich-text-editor, bootstrap-wysiwyg

The problem is if you click the insert hyperlink button in IE 10 and IE 11 you will receive the drop down menu to enter the url, but you can not set focus on the textbox to enter a URL. everytime you click on the box the focus goes inside the below content editable

How to repro:

Open this link http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ in IE 10 and IE 11, click on the icon to add link and click on the URL box and try entering something

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same issue right now.

Comment: @DarrenTaylor, it got worked. The webpages were disabled to edit. When plugin was embedded in the webpage focus was not able to set. By enabling the edit access to web page, focus was set normally.

Answer (score 0):

Just over-ride following CSS class.

```
.dropdown-menu.input-append input {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Aamir's solution, you can also solve this using the following JavaScript snippet.

```
$(".dropdown-menu > input").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```